# Accessing and Controlling an Android Device Remotely

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I tried AirStream and AirDroid but like Teamviewer both are not successful and satisfactory.

What apps can be used for access, controlling and providing support for an android device from another android device and desktop computer?

Regards

GNS

Comment: Upvoted for the Android->Android part - I'd like to know as well. As for PC->Android, tried Splashtop yet?

Comment: You need to be more specific, Sens SMS remotely, Call remotely, Watch the screen etc....

Comment: Like we access, support and control Windows Computer using TeamViewer or Logmein Rescue; I would like to access, support and control an Android Device from another Android Device and Windows Computer.